# (Scrapy pipeline): Unable to create database table as part of Scrapy pipeline script

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm, mariadb, create-table

I am trying to create a database table as part of a Scrapy pipeline script.

My pipelines.py file is as follows:

```
import pymysql.cursors

class mySQLTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='',
                             db='testDB',
                             charset='utf8mb4',
                          cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_target(self):
        sql = "CREATE TABLE items2 (id INT(11) NOT NULL);"

        self.cursor.execute(sql)
        self.conn.commit()
```

When I run the script in the PyCharm Python Console, I can see the table is created.

However, when I run it as part of Scrapy, no table is created.

Does Scrapy pipeline not enable creation of tables?  What is the best way to trace what errors the script may be running into?

Tech Specs:

- Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11
- PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.4
- Python 3.6.1
- Maria DB 10.2.6

Answer (score 0):

=> I suggest you to change the name of method `process_target(self)` to `process_item(self, item)`.
=> Is the item pipeline activated inside settings.py file ?
=> do you yield any object to the pipeline ?